# How to save the image into sqlite database?

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i plce the images in 3 views.And first 2 views are worked well.But in third view images are not saved in database.Below one is my code for updating the images.

```
-(void)updateStaff:(DataBaseFields*)databasefields
{
if(stfupdateStmt == nil) {
    const char *sql = "update FoodBlogger Set update_date_time = ?, Stf_Mgr_Image = ?, Stf_Mgr_Text = ?, Stf_Srvr_Image = ?, Stf_Chf_Image = ?, Stf_Owr_Image= ? Where insert_date_time = ?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stfupdateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_bind_text(stfupdateStmt, 1, [databasefields.update_datetime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_bind_blob(stfupdateStmt, 2, [databasefields.mgrImage bytes], [databasefields.mgrImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_bind_blob(stfupdateStmt, 3, [databasefields.srvrImage bytes], [databasefields.srvrImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_bind_blob(stfupdateStmt, 4, [databasefields.chfImage bytes], [databasefields.chfImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_bind_blob(stfupdateStmt, 5, [databasefields.owrImage bytes], [databasefields.owrImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_bind_text(stfupdateStmt, 6, [databasefields.insert_datetime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(stfupdateStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

sqlite3_reset(stfupdateStmt);
```

}

And image varaible in database type is varchar.Before 2 views are worked correctly.But this view was not working.So please help me how to solve this one.

Comment: How large are your images ? Depending on that it might not be a good idea to store them in sqlite in the first place. Have you considered spring a path and putting the images in the file system? Have you considered using core data ? Can save you a lot effort